# How to limit DNSService to loopback interface?

Tags: ios, network-programming, mdns

I'm trying to implement communication between two iOS apps through a bonjour service. Let's not discuss that this will probably not be accepted by App-Store review. It's not going to be published in the store anyway.

I'm trying to limit a Bonjour announcement for the service to the loopback interface to only allow connections on the same device.

I've implemented the lowlevel DNSServiceRegister method to announce the service in the following way:

```
DNSServiceErrorType err = DNSServiceRegister(  
                                                &dnsServiceRef,  
                                                kDNSServiceFlagsDefault,  
                                                if_nametoindex("lo0"),  //limit to loopback interface
                                                "myServiceName",  
                                                "_myservicetype._tcp",  
                                                NULL,
                                                NULL,
                                                htons(port),  
                                                0,  
                                                NULL,  
                                                &DNSServiceRegisterCallback,  
                                                (__bridge void *)(self)
                              );
```

On the client side I've implemented discovery as follows:

```
DNSServiceErrorType error =  DNSServiceBrowse(&serviceBrowseRef,  
                                                kDNSServiceFlagsDefault,  
                                                if_nametoindex("lo0"), //limit discovery to loopback as well  
                                                "_myservicetype._tcp",  
                                                NULL,  
                                                &serviceBrowseReply,  
                                                (__bridge void *)(self)  
                                                );
```

Testing in the iPhone simulator does not return the expected results. The discovery does not find the announced service.

Some further digging:

Trying to check on command line if it worked `dns-sd -B _myservicetype._tcp` but it finds nothing

Strangely the following `dns-sd -lo -B _myservicetype._tcp` (limit to all local interfaces instead of loopback) shows the expected service but the interfaceIndex is 0 (but if_nametoindex says the index is 1)

Using `kDNSServiceInterfaceIndexLocalOnly` instead of `if_nametoindex("lo0")` as the parameter for `DNSServiceBrowse` returns the announced service.
The interfaceIndex reported in the callback is 0 again (same behavior as the command line tool).

And even stranger if I use `kDNSServiceInterfaceIndexLocalOnly` while registering the service, the interfaceIndex of the discovered service is 4294967295. (uint overflow?)

Is this expected behavior (not allowed to limit to loopback interface?) or am I experiencing some strange bug with the internal handling of interface indices here?

Comment: For now I'm registering and browsing with kDNSServiceInterfaceIndexLocalOnly constants which might use loopback or another local interface.
To be able to connect to the socket which only allows connections over loopback interface I'm dropping the resolved hostname afterwards and use 'localhost' instead

Answer (score 1):

The reason using lo0 doesn't work is because mDNSResponder doesn't use the loopback interface when a real interface (which supports multicast loopback, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP) is registered.  See [UpdateInterfaceList](https://opensource.apple.com/source/mDNSResponder/mDNSResponder-765.30.11/mDNSMacOSX/mDNSMacOSX.c.auto.html) in the MacOS X backend

The DNS SD API has special case index defines which are not valid indexes returned from if_nametoidex(). Normally indexes start at 1, see the documentation from [dns_sd.h](https://opensource.apple.com/source/mDNSResponder/mDNSResponder-765.30.11/mDNSShared/dns_sd.h) on what 0 and -1 mean. Follow the guidance on how to advertise and browse for local-only services:

```
/*
 * Constants for specifying an interface index
 *
 * Specific interface indexes are identified via a 32-bit unsigned integer returned
 * by the if_nametoindex() family of calls.
 *
 * If the client passes 0 for interface index, that means "do the right thing",
 * which (at present) means, "if the name is in an mDNS local multicast domain
 * (e.g. 'local.', '254.169.in-addr.arpa.', '{8,9,A,B}.E.F.ip6.arpa.') then multicast
 * on all applicable interfaces, otherwise send via unicast to the appropriate
 * DNS server." Normally, most clients will use 0 for interface index to
 * automatically get the default sensible behaviour.
 *
 * If the client passes a positive interface index, then for multicast names that
 * indicates to do the operation only on that one interface. For unicast names the
 * interface index is ignored unless kDNSServiceFlagsForceMulticast is also set.
 *
 * If the client passes kDNSServiceInterfaceIndexLocalOnly when registering
 * a service, then that service will be found *only* by other local clients
 * on the same machine that are browsing using kDNSServiceInterfaceIndexLocalOnly
 * or kDNSServiceInterfaceIndexAny.
 * If a client has a 'private' service, accessible only to other processes
 * running on the same machine, this allows the client to advertise that service
 * in a way such that it does not inadvertently appear in service lists on
 * all the other machines on the network.
 *
 * If the client passes kDNSServiceInterfaceIndexLocalOnly when browsing
 * then it will find *all* records registered on that same local machine.
 * Clients explicitly wishing to discover *only* LocalOnly services can
 * accomplish this by inspecting the interfaceIndex of each service reported
 * to their DNSServiceBrowseReply() callback function, and discarding those
 * where the interface index is not kDNSServiceInterfaceIndexLocalOnly.
 *
 * kDNSServiceInterfaceIndexP2P is meaningful only in Browse, QueryRecord,
 * and Resolve operations. It should not be used in other DNSService APIs.
 *
 * - If kDNSServiceInterfaceIndexP2P is passed to DNSServiceBrowse or
 *   DNSServiceQueryRecord, it restricts the operation to P2P.
 *
 * - If kDNSServiceInterfaceIndexP2P is passed to DNSServiceResolve, it is
 *   mapped internally to kDNSServiceInterfaceIndexAny, because resolving
 *   a P2P service may create and/or enable an interface whose index is not
 *   known a priori. The resolve callback will indicate the index of the
 *   interface via which the service can be accessed.
 *
 * If applications pass kDNSServiceInterfaceIndexAny to DNSServiceBrowse
 * or DNSServiceQueryRecord, they must set the kDNSServiceFlagsIncludeP2P flag
 * to include P2P. In this case, if a service instance or the record being queried 
 * is found over P2P, the resulting ADD event will indicate kDNSServiceInterfaceIndexP2P 
 * as the interface index.
 */

 #define kDNSServiceInterfaceIndexAny 0
 #define kDNSServiceInterfaceIndexLocalOnly ((uint32_t)-1)
 #define kDNSServiceInterfaceIndexUnicast   ((uint32_t)-2)
 #define kDNSServiceInterfaceIndexP2P       ((uint32_t)-3)
```